How do I get a random integer if each of them has a different probability?
I want to accurately generate the age of a random person given that there's n0 people who are 0 y/o, n1 people who are 1 y/o e.t.c.
How can I do it?
I found myself to be completely illiterate on this topic.
I want the output to be a single number

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

For this, you can use std::discrete_distribution.
Example:
#include <random>

// …

std::mt19937 prng(std::random_device{}());
double n0 = 1;
double n1 = 2;
double n2 = 7;
std::discrete_distribution<unsigned> dist({n0, n1, n2})

… = dist(prng);

Demo
